# undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I got this error referring to line 3 in the view when I used a form in new action to upload photos.I tried to get multiple photo uploaded. Photo is attached to the item and the item is added to the poll. The relavant codes are:

```
-# new view
%h1 Upload item pictures
= form_for(@poll, :html => {:multipart => true }) do |f|
  - @poll.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
    %p = msg
  %fieldset
    = f.label :title
    = f.text_field :title
  %fieldset
    Pending Attachments: (Max of #{Item::Max_Attachments}) each under #{Item::Max_Attachment_Size/1.megabyte} MB)
    - if @poll.items.count >= Item::Max_Attachments
      <input id="newfile_data" type="file" disabled />
    - else 
      %input{:id => "newfile_data", :type => "file"}
    #attachment_list
      %ul{:id => "pending_files"}
  %fieldset
    = f.submit "Create"

class PollsController < ApplicationController
  # POST /polls
  def create
    @poll = Poll.new(params[:poll])   
    process_file_uploads(@poll)
    if @poll.save
      flash[:notice] = 'poll was successfully created.'
      redirect_to(@poll)
    else
      render :action => "new" 
    end
  end
  private
  def process_file_uploads(poll)
    i = 0
    while params[:attachment]['file_'+i.to_s] != "" && !params[:attachment]['file_'+i.to_s].nil?
      poll.items.build(:photo => params[:attachment]['file_'+i.to_s])
      i += 1
    end
  end
end

class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items  
end
```

Are there anything wrong in my codes? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Just need to define new in polls_controller like

```
def new
  @poll = Poll.new 
end
```

And it works!